# Cannot create multiple mongo connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm following a tutorial to make an authentication API, and it says that I should connect to the database on each request to insert my data, it goes pretty much like this.

This is just a snippet from the code.

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
mongoose.connect(connUri, { useNewUrlParser: true  }, (err) => {
        let result = {};
        if (!err) {
            User.findOne({email}, (err, user) => {
                if (!err && user) {
    // the rest of function here
```

and then I have the same thing going on another function.

```
exports.add = (req, res) => {
    console.log(connUri);
    mongoose.connect(connUri, { useNewUrlParser: true  }, (err) => {
        let result = {};
        if (!err) {
            const email = req.body.email;
                      // the rest here
```

But now whenever I make a request, I get an error saying You can not `mongoose.connect()` multiple times while connected.
After Googling a bit I understand the issue, and the best solution for my case is to make one global `mongoose.connect()` - but then I wouldn't be able to set the `err` callback that's already on those functions checks.

Is there a way to do this while keeping the current code structure as it is?

Comment: I'm not sure why your tutorial suggests that you need to connect multiple times. It seems nonsensical to me. Do you have a link? Also: The callback is there to wait for the db-connection. Once you're connected you don't really have to worry about it anymore. Why would you want to set it again?

Comment: It's good practice to reuse database connections. Why exactly do you want to create multiple connections?

Comment: @jayms https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-es6-api-with-json-web-tokens this is the link.

Comment: @Sterex like I explained, I was simply following a tutorial since I'm still very new to this, and this is how it was.

Comment: Yeah, that is the trouble with tutorials. They introduce bad practices sometimes and it takes more time to unlearn and relearn. In any case, the ideal way to handle database connections in express would be to connect to the database when you are creating the HTTP server. More info here: https://blog.mlab.com/2017/05/mongodb-connection-pooling-for-express-applications/

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of this tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help either way! Glad I could find out about this before I went too far with it.